# How to get rid of nullability warning in an objective c typedef?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

This code produces a "pointer is missing a nullability type specifier" warning in XCode and I can't guess how to silence the warning.

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyClass : NSObject

typedef id (^MyBlock)(id object);

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

The following don't silence the warning:

```
typedef __nonnull id (^MyBlock)(__nonnull id object);
typedef nonnull id (^MyBlock)(nonnull id object);
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> typedef types don’t usually have an inherent nullability—they can
>   easily be either nullable or non-nullable depending on the context.
>   Therefore, **typedef types are not assumed to be nonnull, even within
>   audited regions**.[[1]](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25)

Below syntax is working fine

```
typedef __nonnull id (^MyBlock)(__nonnull id object);
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right it does work. I had to build clean to get xcode to discard the warning though.

Comment: Do you have a source for your quote? I recently reported this bug to clang, but if I'm obviously wrong, I'd like to know. :)

Comment: @HeathBorders Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25